# Exibir imagens do Facebook com determinada hashtag via API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, facebook

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web, e meu cliente me questionou a respeito de aparecer na aplicação dele, em alguma área do site, imagens do **Facebook**, com a **hashtag desejada**.

Exemplo, ele vai cobrir um determinado exemplo, os clientes dele tiram fotos e publicam no Facebook com a hashtag `#EventoDoFulano`, e essas fotos são exibidas no site dele.

Estou desenvolvendo essa aplicação utilizando ASP.NET MVC 5, com jQuery em frontend. Mas soluções são bem vindas em Web Forms também.

Comment: Você precisa ver a API de cada rede social em separado. Cada uma trata isso de forma diferente. Daí você pode criar classes no seu sistema que agregam esses dados. Eu sei que o que eu falei parece meio óbvio, mas o ponto do conselho é esse: estude a API de cada rede.

Comment: @Renan Mas assim, outra dúvida minha que pode ser meio besta, vou pegar cada api em separado, beleza. Mas por exemplo, tem uma api especifica para o que eu quero, ou são api's "gerais" ?

Comment: Cada rede social tem uma, e até onde eu sei apenas uma API própria. E você precisa usar a API de cada rede que for utilizada pela sua solução. Eu não sei se existe uma API de terceiros que unifique as chamadas a todas as redes.

Comment: @Renan cara, valeu pela ajuda, acredito que já vai me ajudar ao menos tomar um norte em minhas pesquisas para desenvolver este modulo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acho que você consegue utilizando o GRAPH API.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=#EventoDoFulano&limit=10000&access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN

Comment: Obrigado @GeiltonXavier,isso já ajuda bastante.